# Writing a function using lambda and apply

Tags: scheme

I'm attempting to write a function that takes an argument that is essentially a function and will return the converse of that function. I am to achieve this through using lambda and apply. Here is what I have so far...it does not work at the moment because I can't seem to figure out how to define a lambda function that will take any number of arguments. Any additional help is much appreciated.

```
(define foobar (lambda (F) (lambda x(apply not (map x F)))))
```

Example output:

((L3 <) 4 3) --> #t

((L3 <) 3 4) --> #f

((L3 <) 3 3) --> #t

((L3 (L3 <)) 3 4) --> #t

((L3 (L3 <)) 4 3) --> #f

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple implementation of the `negate` function:

```
;; negate : (Any * -> Boolean) -> (Any * -> Boolean)
(define (negate f)
  (lambda args
    (not (apply f args))))
```